# A DateTimePicker to change only month and year

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, datetimepicker

UI should remain same I don't want to do this:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "mm-yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

A User can pick the year and month, change DateTimePicker to Month/Year picker, the MonthCalendar too.
I don't want to use a third-party control but I will if it will be the only answer point me to any free month/year picker control.

Comment: Have you considered just using two dropdowns (one for month and one for year)? With ordinary dates, a calendar is helpful so the user can see what day of the week a particular date is; when picking just a month and year, that feature is not quite as helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple DateTimePicker custom control that pre-defines a custom DateTime format and modified the [MonthCalendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-control-reference) view, *configuring* it show just the Months and the Year when is opened.

I've added a public property, **`ShowToday`**, that allows to specify whether the MonthCalendar popup should show the `Today` date at the bottom of the Calendar interface.

The custom control overrides [OnDropDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.ondropdown) to get the Handle of the MonthCalendar popup, sending a [`DTM_GETMONTHCAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-getmonthcal) message and changes its current view sending a [`MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/mcm-setcurrentview), specifying **`MCMV_YEAR`** as the value parameter.

This is how it look like:

[image: DateTimePicker Custom Month Year only]

---

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
class DateTimePickerYearMonth : DateTimePicker
{
    public DateTimePickerYearMonth() {
        this.CustomFormat = "MM-yyyy";
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        this.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [
        Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(false),
        Category("Appearance"), 
        Description("Shows or hides \"Today\" date at the bottom of the Calendar Control")
    ]
    public bool ShowToday {
        get => m_ShowToday;
        set {
            if (value != m_ShowToday) {
                m_ShowToday = value;
                ShowMonCalToday(m_ShowToday);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        ShowMonCalToday(m_ShowToday);
    }

    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        var hWnd = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
            SendMessage(hWnd, MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW, 0, (int)MonCalView.MCMV_YEAR);
        }
        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }

    private void ShowMonCalToday(bool show)
    {
        int styles = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMCSTYLE, 0, 0).ToInt32();
        styles = show ? styles &~(int)MonCalStyles.MCS_NOTODAY : styles | (int)MonCalStyles.MCS_NOTODAY;
        SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, 0, styles);
    }
        
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private const int DTM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int DTM_GETMONTHCAL = DTM_FIRST + 8;
    private const int DTM_SETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 11;
    private const int DTM_GETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 12;
    private const int MCM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int MCM_GETCURRENTVIEW = MCM_FIRST + 22;
    private const int MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW = MCM_FIRST + 32;
    private bool m_ShowToday = false;

    public enum MonCalView : int
    {
        MCMV_MONTH = 0,
        MCMV_YEAR = 1,
        MCMV_DECADE = 2,
        MCMV_CENTURY = 3
    }

    public enum MonCalStyles : int
    {
        MCS_DAYSTATE = 0x0001,
        MCS_MULTISELECT = 0x0002,
        MCS_WEEKNUMBERS = 0x0004,
        MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE = 0x0008,
        MCS_NOTODAY = 0x0010,
        MCS_NOTRAILINGDATES = 0x0040,
        MCS_SHORTDAYSOFWEEK = 0x0080,
        MCS_NOSELCHANGEONNAV = 0x0100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom format is to be used to determine the way the date should be captured in the system/database irrespective of what the user selected, it is not used to restrict the user to choosing either month or year.