# How can I disable 'MonthCalendar' and Datetimepicker 's visual style for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, monthcalendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d3S2.png)

I want to fill monthcalendar for my form..

but it didn't work, I figured out the problem is 'Visual style'.

So, I tried `Application.VisualStyleState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled`

It works but it makes looking weird my whole program.. ;(

How can I disable only  'MonthCalendar' and Datetimepicker 's visual style? (for VB.NET)

Please, Help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [SetWindowTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme) function to disable the theme for individual controls.

First, add the following class to your program:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Shared Function SetWindowTheme(hWnd As IntPtr,
                                          pszSubAppName As String,
                                          pszSubIdList As String) As Integer
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, you can simply do something like this:

```
NativeMethods.SetWindowTheme(DateTimePicker1.Handle, String.Empty, String.Empty)
NativeMethods.SetWindowTheme(MonthCalendar1.Handle, String.Empty, String.Empty)
```

**Result:**

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before] | [image: After] |

---

Disabling the theme for the MonthCalendar created by the DateTimePicker is a little trickier. Because DateTimePicker dynamically creates it when you click the dropdown button, you'll have to handle the `DropDown` event of the DateTimePicker, get the handle of the MonthCalender, and then disable its theme. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690597/8967612) for more information.

Here's an example:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Const DTM_GETMONTHCAL As Integer = &H1008

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.DropDown
    Dim calendarHandle = SendMessage(DateTimePicker1.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0)
    If calendarHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        NativeMethods.SetWindowTheme(calendarHandle, String.Empty, String.Empty)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for monthcalendar but not Datetimepicker how can I do?

Comment: @ReaznK What exactly happens (or doesn't happen) when you apply it to the DateTimePicker?

Comment: It looks like datetimepicker hasn't visual style. but when I click the datetimepicker, the calendar that is showing below the datetimepicker has still system visual style.

Comment: @ReaznK I've added that to the answer.