# Datetimepicker months and years only in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, windows-forms-designer

It is possible in datetimepicker can pick months and years only without date? I didn't see any properties to remove the date pick. If someone have an idea please share. It would be appreciated. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: FYI, when you add an image and the editor adds the boilerplate text "enter image description here", you supposed to enter the image description there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690597/14171304

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTimePicker.Value` property is type `DateTime` so you will always get a `DateTime` from that no matter what. You can just ignore the parts you don't want, of course. If you only want the date, you ignore the time portion. If you only want the month and year, you can ignore the day too.

As for the control itself, you can set the `ShowUpDown` property to `True` and then the drop-down button will be replaced with spinner buttons, so the user will be able to increment and decrement individual parts of the displayed value rather than display the drop-down calendar. You can also set the `Format` to `Custom` and then the `CustomFormat` to whatever you want displayed, e.g. "yyyy/MM". The control will then display just the year and the month and the spinner buttons can be used to set them.

As I said, you'll still get a full `DateTime` from the `Value` property but you can just get the `Year` and `Month` of that, or use the `Text` of the control if you actually want a `String`.

Looking at your image again, I'm thinking that maybe you want to keep the drop-down calendar but only the year and month sections. That is not possible.